# Can we allow in-app purchase to unlock iMessage app functionality. Is this possible?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, imessage-extension

iMessage extension show when in-app Purchase done, is this Possible in iOS.

Comment: Consider adding a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What have you already tried? What isn't working? The more detail and code you can provide the better.

Comment: no, it not possible. you might be able to unlock extra functionality, but not whole imessage extension